# How to know which service fire this __InstanceModificationEvent event?

Tags: c#, events, service, wmi, wmi-query

I have simple codes to track service state. But in my code, i can just know service started or  stopped. I want to know which service started or stopped.

Here is my code samples.
This is main function:

```
public void TrackService()
        {
            string queryRunning = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_Service\" AND TargetInstance.State=\"Running\"";
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = null;
            watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(queryRunning);
            watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(ServiceStart);
            watcher.Start();
        }
```

This is event func.

```
private void ServiceStart(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = "Services has started.";
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257355%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  while searching it.

```
private void ServiceStart(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string msg = ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"])["DisplayName"];
        }
```

This is what i want. `(ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"])`.